# Enterprise Library 6 ExecuteSprocAccessor overload?

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, enterprise-library, enterprise-library-6

Regarding the new version of *Microsoft Enterprise Libarary 6* , they have a method called `ExecuteSprocAccessor` (*which should return `Ienumerable<T>` when execute SP*) which all its overload are :

[image]

Usage example :

```
/*1*/   [Description("Return data as a sequence of objects using a stored procedure")]
/*2*/           static void ReadDataAsObjects()
/*3*/           {
/*4*/               // Create an object array and populate it with the required parameter values
/*5*/               object[] paramArray = new object[] { "%bike%" };
/*6*/               // Create and execute a sproc accessor that uses default parameter and outpu`t mappings
/*7*/               IEnumerable<Product> productData = defaultDB.ExecuteSprocAccessor<Product>("GetProductList", paramArray);
/*8*/               //...
/*9*/               //...
/*10*/           }
```

<kbd>Additional Info :</kbd>

The parameter adding mechanism (here) is very problematic because there is no `ParameterName to value` association.

all they do there is (at line 5)

`object[] paramArray = new object[] { "%bike%" };`

So I guess If I have more then 1 param it will look  like :

`object[] paramArray = new object[] { "%bike%",19,"lala"... };`

which means that I'll have to know the order of sp's param input order !!!

NB

Other methods do have this sort of attaching values to name :

`defaultDB.AddInParameter(sprocCmd, "state", DbType.String, "New York");`

<kbd>Question</kbd>

Is there any way of using `ExecuteSprocAccessor` and still do  `ParameterName to value` association ? (assuming I don't know the sp input param order ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Internally an `IParameterMapper` is used which is a really simple interface:

```
public interface IParameterMapper
{
    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="command"></param>
    /// <param name="parameterValues"></param>
    void AssignParameters(DbCommand command, object[] parameterValues);
}
```

It's all based on positions so there is not much that can be done with the out of the box code.

One option is to write your own Accessor that uses a custom parameter mapper that knows how to use parameter names.  You can find an example of this in the thread [Entlib6 DAAB - Using accessors to execute stored procedures with optional parameters?](http://entlib.codeplex.com/discussions/443904).

Comment: just wonders : they did do the `ParameterName to value` (AddInParameter) matching with other methods. why not here also ?